# Game Center Completion Banner not showing in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, game-center, ios14

I'm trying to integrate Game Center into my iOS app. However, the achievement completion banner doesn't appear even if I set the `ShowsCompletionBanner` flag to `true`. I've been testing my app through iOS Simulator with iOS 14.

[image]

I'm using the following code (Xamarin.iOS):

```
var achievement = new GKAchievement("sample.achievement")
{
    PercentComplete = 100,
    ShowsCompletionBanner = true
};

achievement.ReportAchievement(null);
```

I can confirm that the `ReportAchievement` has succeeded since the achievement has been unlocked in the achievements view (`GKGameCenterViewControllerState.achievements`)

**Added info:** The completion banner appears when I put a breakpoint at the `achievement.ReportAchievement(null)` line. Also tried using `achievement.ReportAchievementAsync()` but I'm still encountering the same behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you try this on real device to see if problem persists?

Answer (score 0):

Try using static ReportAchievements instead of instance method being used.
You can see that in the Apple developer document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkachievement?language=objc

But we also want info in where the API is being called from as there still may be an issue with async and timing.
Might be worth using a completion handler with the synchronous method which may reveal an error.